# release object in the @synchronized scope

Tags: ios, deadlock, synchronized

I have a question, what if I use **synchronized** to lock the object but I release it at the scope. Does it cause deadlock?

```
- (void)doSomething {   
   @synchronized(self) {
       // Release self over here
   }
}

[SomeObject doSomething];
[SomeObject doSomething];
```

Comment: Why would you ever release `self`? Anyway, don't release objects - use ARC.

Comment: In the ARC, you might release the object itself at the scope too.

Comment: You don't explicity release objects with ARC and an object can't be released while its code is executing - well, I can imagine a convoluted construct where you nil the property of another object that is holding the reference to *this* object, but still the object won't be deallocated until the method exits